# Как в JS изменить style="background-color:" через контекст this

Tags: javascript, html

Хочу изменить через style="background-color:" напрямую , не вызывая

```
document.getElementById(this.id).style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
```

а записав его напрямую в контекст this, в принципе это работает, то есть можно например сделать так

```
<input type="text" id="old_id" style="background-color: #ffb3b3" onkeyup="input_fn(this)">
```

и затем сделать

```
function input_fn() {this.id = "new_id"}
```

и в хроме всё прекрасно работает, id элемента изменит значение, но вот в ОЧЕНЬ длинном списке this'а я ненашёл ничего подобного **style** , может кто подскажет где он там запрятан ??

Comment: так я не понял, в итоге вы хотите id поменять или style? что это за функция `function () {this.id = "new_id"}` и где она вызывается? зачем делать так `document.getElementById(this.id)` если уже есть _this_?

Comment: изменить то я хочу style, я просто привёл пример что это работает, пока не встречал такой способ работы с элементами DOM и незнаю насколько он валиден, чисто технически проблем быть не должно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function input_fn(elem){
  elem.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="old_id" style="background-color: #ffb3b3" onkeyup="input_fn(this)">
```

Comment: спасибо , всё работает, странно что в console.dir этого объекта не показывает атрибута style

Comment: Perkovec у нас с тобой просто карма в действии :)

Comment: @vnn198 непонял, что?

Comment: ну если помнишь я тебе когда то помог с запуском экзешника в ноде :)